# Postman: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: ''

Tags: php, json, rest, postman

I'm procedding the PHP REST API From Scratch from TraversyMedia channel on youtube, in which the Postman is used to check if everything is working appripriately.

The repository with the code is [here](https://github.com/bradtraversy/php_rest_myblog)

In Postman I receive following error and dont know, how to fix it.

> Notice: Trying to get property 'title' of non-object in
>   /var/www/html/php_rest_myblog/api/post/create.php on line 21
>
> Notice: Trying to get property 'body' of non-object in
>   /var/www/html/php_rest_myblog/api/post/create.php on line 22
>
> Notice: Trying to get property 'author' of non-object in
>   /var/www/html/php_rest_myblog/api/post/create.php on line 23
>
> Notice: Trying to get property 'category_id' of non-object in
>   /var/www/html/php_rest_myblog/api/post/create.php on line 24
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error:
>   1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'category_id' at row 1 in
>   /var/www/html/php_rest_myblog/models/Post.php:91 Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/html/php_rest_myblog/models/Post.php(91):
>   PDOStatement->execute() #1
>   /var/www/html/php_rest_myblog/api/post/create.php(27): Post->create()
>
> ## 2 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/php_rest_myblog/models/Post.php on line 91

The code from post.php is following:

```
 <?php 
  class Post {
    // DB stuff
    private $conn;
    private $table = 'posts';

    // Post Properties
    public $id;
    public $category_id;
    public $category_name;
    public $title;
    public $body;
    public $author;
    public $created_at;

    // Constructor with DB
    public function __construct($db) {
      $this->conn = $db;
    }

    // Get Posts
    public function read() {
      // Create query
      $query = 'SELECT c.name as category_name, p.id, p.category_id, p.title, p.body, p.author, p.created_at
                                FROM ' . $this->table . ' p
                                LEFT JOIN
                                  categories c ON p.category_id = c.id
                                ORDER BY
                                  p.created_at DESC';

      // Prepare statement
      $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

      // Execute query
      $stmt->execute();

      return $stmt;
    }

    // Get Single Post
    public function read_single() {
          // Create query
          $query = 'SELECT c.name as category_name, p.id, p.category_id, p.title, p.body, p.author, p.created_at
                                    FROM ' . $this->table . ' p
                                    LEFT JOIN
                                      categories c ON p.category_id = c.id
                                    WHERE
                                      p.id = ?
                                    LIMIT 0,1';

          // Prepare statement
          $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

          // Bind ID
          $stmt->bindParam(1, $this->id);

          // Execute query
          $stmt->execute();

          $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

          // Set properties
          $this->title = $row['title'];
          $this->body = $row['body'];
          $this->author = $row['author'];
          $this->category_id = $row['category_id'];
          $this->category_name = $row['category_name'];
    }

    // Create Post
    public function create() {
          // Create query
          $query = 'INSERT INTO ' . $this->table . ' SET title = :title, body = :body, author = :author, category_id = :category_id';

          // Prepare statement
          $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

          // Clean data
          $this->title = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->title));
          $this->body = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->body));
          $this->author = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->author));
          $this->category_id = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->category_id));

          // Bind data
          $stmt->bindParam(':title', $this->title);
          $stmt->bindParam(':body', $this->body);
          $stmt->bindParam(':author', $this->author);
          $stmt->bindParam(':category_id', $this->category_id);

          // Execute query
          if($stmt->execute()) {
            return true;
      }

      // Print error if something goes wrong
      printf("Error: %s.\n", $stmt->error);

      return false;
    }

    // Update Post
    public function update() {
          // Create query
          $query = 'UPDATE ' . $this->table . '
                                SET title = :title, body = :body, author = :author, category_id = :category_id
                                WHERE id = :id';

          // Prepare statement
          $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

          // Clean data
          $this->title = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->title));
          $this->body = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->body));
          $this->author = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->author));
          $this->category_id = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->category_id));
          $this->id = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->id));

          // Bind data
          $stmt->bindParam(':title', $this->title);
          $stmt->bindParam(':body', $this->body);
          $stmt->bindParam(':author', $this->author);
          $stmt->bindParam(':category_id', $this->category_id);
          $stmt->bindParam(':id', $this->id);

          // Execute query
          if($stmt->execute()) {
            return true;
          }

          // Print error if something goes wrong
          printf("Error: %s.\n", $stmt->error);

          return false;
    }

    // Delete Post
    public function delete() {
          // Create query
          $query = 'DELETE FROM ' . $this->table . ' WHERE id = :id';

          // Prepare statement
          $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

          // Clean data
          $this->id = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->id));

          // Bind data
          $stmt->bindParam(':id', $this->id);

          // Execute query
          if($stmt->execute()) {
            return true;
          }

          // Print error if something goes wrong
          printf("Error: %s.\n", $stmt->error);

          return false;
    }

  }
```

and from the create.php the code is following:

```
    <?php 
  // Headers
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST');
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Headers,Content-Type,Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Authorization, X-Requested-With');

  include_once '../../config/Database.php';
  include_once '../../models/Post.php';

  // Instantiate DB & connect
  $database = new Database();
  $db = $database->connect();

  // Instantiate blog post object
  $post = new Post($db);

  // Get raw posted data
  $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

  $post->title = $data->title;
  $post->body = $data->body;
  $post->author = $data->author;
  $post->category_id = $data->category_id;

  // Create post
  if($post->create()) {
    echo json_encode(
      array('message' => 'Post Created')
    );
  } else {
    echo json_encode(
      array('message' => 'Post Not Created')
    );
  }
```

Comment: What does `$data` contain exactly? You should do a `var_dump()` and add the results here.

Comment: I did, and $data contains NULL

Comment: So you are not posting valid json to your api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the bindValue() assumes a string datatype. If you want to use  INT values, you need to specify that to the call

```
$stmt->bindParam(':category_id', $this->category_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```